# Possibilities of the end of digits and quadratic residues

Tags: number-theory

**Problem:** Suppose $\gcd(a,10) = 1$. Show that if the last $n$ digits of $a^2$ are given, where $a$ is an integer, then there are exactly $2, 4,$ or $8$ of the possibilities for the last $n$ digits of $a$, according as $n=1, n=2,$ or $n\geq 3.$

**My Attempt:** Consider $x^2 \equiv a^2 \mod(10^n)$. We need to show that the number of solutions are $2, 4,$ or $8$ according as $n=1, n=2,$ or $n\geq 3.$

I'm not sure how to proceed and finish the proof using quadratic residues. Any ideas?

Comment: How-many-to-one is the map $x\mapsto x^2$ on $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$?